# html page start from diff position

Tags: html, css

have completely no idea where to start so I apologise about the lack of code presented to you.

My problem is - I have a page of information, ordered by ID (gathered from the database). These ID's are referenced from another page to which the user clicks on a link and it takes them to the page with the information on, how ever, there could be potentially hundreds of ID's on that page - So I need to reference each specific ID so when the user clicks, it will take them to the exact position of the ID.
how to achieve it using anchor tag?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your "page of information", place an anchor tag before each block of information. You can leave the anchor tag empty if you want:

`<a name="info_{{ ID }}"></a>`

Replace {{ ID }} with whatever ID you are using.

On your page with all the links to the information, add a fragment identifier to the end of the URL corresponding to the above `name` attribute:

`<a href="page_of_information.html#info_{{ ID }}">Click Here</a>`

So, if your ID's are numeric, and your 'information' resides in `<p>` tags, your code might look like this:

```
<a name="info_1"></a>
<p>...</p>
<a name="info_2"></a>
<p>...</p>
<a name="info_3"></a>
<p>...</p>
<a name="info_4"></a>
<p>...</p>
```

and

```
<a href="page_of_information.html#info_1">Click Here</a>
<a href="page_of_information.html#info_2">Click Here</a>
<a href="page_of_information.html#info_3">Click Here</a>
<a href="page_of_information.html#info_4">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: it is not working brow the page is opening from start and can this name tag use for paragraph?

Comment: @vishal Edited. Hopefully that clears things up